# How can I get back an array of objects from Worker?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-worker

I have a simple `Pixel` pseudoclass that has `.H()`, `.S()` and `.L()` methods. I use these in image analysis - like this watermark detection:

[image: saturation diferential]

To get the objects out of ImageData, I just loop through the ImageData and create multi-dimensional array:

```
  //Get image data
  var id = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
  //The Uint8 array
  var pixels = id.data;
  //Dimensions
  var length = pixels.length;
  var width = id.width;
  var height = id.height;
  //Create empty array for 2D data
  var pixels2D = [];
  //Loop vertically
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    //Create 2nd level array
    pixels2D.push([]);            
    //Cache the vertical offset
    var ofy = y * width;
    //Loop horizontally
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      //Calculate X offset
      var off = (ofy + x) * 4;
      //Create new object
      pixels2D[y].push(new Pixel([pixels[off], pixels[off + 1], pixels[off + 2], pixels[off + 3]]));
    }
  }
```

For large images, this takes a while. Recetly, I found out about [`Workers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers). It seems like the best way to perform asynchronous CPU-demanding tasks, so that my browser doesn't freeze.

It's possible to [pass `UInt8Array` to worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Passing_data_by_transferring_ownership_(transferable_objects)) - but how can I then retrieve the *pseudo-Class instance* array? *Pseudo-Class instances* in javascript can't be serialised...

Comment: Objects *can* be serialized. Class instances with *methods* cannot be serialized.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question. The thing is, that javascript definition of "objects" rather suits a mapped array...