# Can I smuggle custom constructors in the toJSON overriden method?

Tags: javascript, json, prototypal-inheritance

The `JSON.stringify` behavior can be altered by overriding `.toJSON` method:

```
var obj = {toJSON: function() {return [1,2,3];}};
var x = JSON.stringify(dd); 
console.log(x);  // "[1,2,3]"
JSON.parse(x);   // [1,2,3]
```

I'd like to pass the javascript pseudo-class instances (objects inheriting from other objects). However it doesn't seem possible to add any function call in the data:

```
function Pseudoclass(x) {
    this.x = x;
    //More operations
}
```

If you return function, `.stringify` fails. Not talking about the fact that it doesn't seem very possible to pass the class properties:

```
//JSON.stringify(inst) will be undefined
Pseudoclass.prototype.toJSON = function() { 
    //If converted to string, the function loses variables from this scope
    return function() {return new Pseudoclass();};
}
```

If you return string, it's encoded as string:

```
//JSON.stringify(inst) returns "\"Pseudoclass.fromJSON(6)\"" if x was 6
Pseudoclass.prototype.toJSON = function() { 
    return "Pseudoclass.fromJSON("+this.x+")";
}
```

So does anybody has any hacks in mind? I'd use this to [pass prepared class instances to Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508887/how-can-i-get-back-an-array-of-objects-from-worker#comment41650478_26508887) - the only option there is figuring this JSON question or a custom format.

Don't forget that the **constructor call may not be the only way**. All I need is that the object inherits from my predefined object!

Comment: `toJSON` has to return something that is convertible to JSON. A function is not.

Comment: That's why I'm asking if somebody can think a way around that. When there's a rule I tend to ask if it can be broken... Don't restrict yourself to think about things like they were definite :)

Comment: Well, JSON only supports a specific set of "data types". So you have to represent your data as such. E.g. you could represent an instance of `Pseudoclass` as `{class: 'Pseudoclass', data: {x: ...}}`. Then you also have to provide a corresponding deserialization method.

Comment: JSON is very precisely specified, and the set of things that can be property values does not include function objects. You can do something like encode the function code itself as a string and store that, but your decoder would have to know how to instantiate that. It really is something out of the domain that JSON encoding was intended to serve.